# Remove certain keys from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

I'm trying to construct a dictionary that contains a series of sets:

```
{Field1:{Value1, Value2, Value3}, Field2{Value4}}
```

The trouble is, I then wish to delete any fields from the dictionary that only have one value in the set.  I have been writing code like this:

```
for field in FieldSet:
    if len(FieldSet[field]) == 1:
        del(FieldSet[field])
```

But receive the error "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during execution".  (Not surprising, since that's what I'm doing.)  It's not the be-all and end-all if I have to knock together some sort of workaround, but is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Iterate over the return value from [`.keys()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) instead. Since you get a list of keys back, it won't be affected by changing the dictionary after you've called it.

Comment: That is to say, replace the first line with this: `for field in FieldSet.keys():`

Comment: I'm actually using python3, so the corrected line was: 
for field in list(FieldSet.keys()):

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary to convert to a list in this case.

Comment: Maybe, but it seemed to continue to throw the same error with the code Smashery suggested.

Comment: The list conversion is necessary in this case since the generator is lazily-evaluated, and thus on its own, it's susceptible to modifications mid-iteration. Converting to list pulls out all the keys before the iteration begins.

Answer (score 14):

A sometimes-preferable alternative to changing `FieldSet` in place is sometimes (depending on the amount of alterations performed) to build a new one and bind it to the existing name:

```
FieldSet = dict((k, v) for k, v in FieldSet.iteritems()
                if len(v) != 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the pop method.  It removes the element that a key calls.  With respect to your example this looks like:

```
for field in FieldSet.keys():
    if len(FieldSet[field]) == 1:
        FieldSet.pop(field)
```

This is in python 3.2, but I'm not sure if it's a new feature:
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop

Just tried it and it works as advertised.