# How to build a new defaultdict(list) in place based on an existing dictionary of the same type and use the original name

Tags: python, collections, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, there is some overlap in the keys (and values) once they are both built I want to remove from one of them the key, values that exist in the other.  Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800373/remove-certain-keys-from-a-dictionary-in-python) and Alex Martelli's answer I tried

```
from collections import defaultdict

some_dictionary  # a defaultdict(list)
other_dictionary # a defaultdict(list) has some duplicate k,v pairs

other_dictionary = defaultdict((key,other_dictionary[key]) for key in other_dictionary if key not in some_dictionary)
```

When I do this I get an error

```
TypeError: first argument must be callable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
other_dictionary = defaultdict(list, ((k, v) for k, v in other_dictionary.iteritems() if k not in some_dictionary))
```

Notice that a `defaultdict` must receive a *callable* as its first argument, for determining what's the default value. In your code, the `list` argument was missing.

Other than that, your algorithm was essentially correct - but it can be written a bit more concisely using `iteritems()`, as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Use iteritems

```
other_dictionary = defaultdict(list, ((key,values) for key, values in other_dictionary.iteritems() if key not in some_dictionary))
```